# Trying to Debug Dynamic Forms in Django - logging SQL

Tags: python, django, debugging, logging, python-logging

Context: I've recently taken on Web Development responsibilities at my job. I'm not 100% familiar with Django or our codebase yet.

Our staff intranet has dynamic forms for different accident reports. We have a non-employee accident report that functions perfectly, and an employee accident form that is currently not functioning. The code is nearly identical less a few different fields for each. When the form is submitted, the page will provide a summary of the info you entered to be approved for publication. This works on the non-employee form, but not on the employee form. When I submit the bugged form, the form data exists in the payload and the post request returns a 200 response. At this point we are thinking that it is a database issue, but there isn't any debugging implemented.

We are trying to implement some debugging, but I can't get anything to display in the console, though I do think I am pretty confused.

IMPORTANT NOTE: We are on a super outdated version of django: 1.11

This is what I have in my settings.py file. Everything I have found and read online says that this should print SQL statements to the console. But I'm not positive if I need to add something anywhere else.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    }
}
```

Is there something I need to add in my `views.py` file where the form is actually being handled?

Comment: Oh, and DEBUG = True in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

If both the forms are present in a single html template then make sure to change their input id and names and do a test as you said, form data exists in the payload so you can have a look at the form post endpoint and print which form data you are getting

Worst case scenario, Db schema is not matching with form schema so look into that as well

You can something like Django toolbar [Link](https://linuxhint.com/enable-debug-mode-in-django/) to debug further